# How to reset Git repository to old sate without moving the HEAD

Tags: git

I want to reset Git repository to state from some other commit (have in my working directory only the files from that commit and in versions from that commit), but I don't want to move HEAD of the branch (which would be done by `git reset`), leave all the commit history intact.

What is the way to do that?

Comment: I don't know if git can do that. You could use git diff to make a patch file, then apply that in the normal way, not using git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**WARNING THIS WILL DELETE UNTRACKED FILES AND DISCARD ALL CHANGES** but that’s what you asked for:

> have in my working directory only the files from that commit

Delete tracked files (don’t forget the `git` in front of this, `rm -rf .` is quite different):

```
git rm -rf .
```

Delete untracked files, including ignored ones:

```
git clean -fdx
```

(There is only `.git` now)

Check out the files from the revision you want without checking out the revision itself:

```
git checkout some-other-commit -- .
```